# On GridView edit, "Input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am working on my first asp.net project and can't seem to get past this error. The next step is to calculate the difference between two values (each in a separate gridview) and display the difference in a textbox. For debugging I have a textbox to display each value, so right now there are 3 textboxes. One of the values is in an editable gridview, when I click edit I get the following exception:

> System.FormatException occurred Message=Input string was not in a
>   correct format. Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles
>   options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean
>   parseDecimal)
>          at System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles
>   options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
>          at System.Decimal.Parse(String s)
>          at
>   caremaster.caremaster.FieldDetailsGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender,
>   GridViewRowEventArgs e) in M:\My Documents\file.cs:line 48
>   InnerException:

Here is a code sample:

```
protected void TotalNGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string totNUnits = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
        unitsN.Text = totNUnits;
        applied = decimal.Parse(e.Row.Cells[0].Text.ToString())                    
    }
}

protected void FieldDetailsGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string recNUnits = e.Row.Cells[4].Text;
        recomN.Text = recNUnits;
        recommend = decimal.Parse(e.Row.Cells[4].Text.ToString()); // exception thrown
        calcNtoApply();
    }           
}

protected void calcNtoApply()
{
    decimal final;
    final = recommend - applied;           
    finalN.Text = final.ToString();
}
```

Right now I am retrieving the data on `GridView_RowDataBound`. I think I'm confused between the differences in gridview events. Since this error happens when "edit" is clicked, should I be retrieving the value for recommend in `RowDataEditing`?

Here are some additional details:

```
decimal recommend; 

decimal applied;
```

Thanks in advance for any criticism and guidance.

Comment: When you debug, what is the value of `e.Row.Cells[4].Text`? Btw, you don't need to use `.ToString()` at `e.Row.Cells[4].Text.ToString()` since `.Text` is already of type string.

Comment: The value is 250, for testing I edit and change it to 251. Thanks for the heads up on ToString(), I was trying a bunch of crazy stuff trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Decimal.TryParse` method.

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[4].Text))
 decimal.TryParse(e.Row.Cells[4].Text,out recommend);
```

Comment: @rdizzler, I voted for this as well. However, since it's a `TryParse`, you won't have a value for `recommend` all the time. You're just suppressing the exception. Are you now getting the output as you're supposed to?

Comment: The output is working as expected. Thanks for bringing this to my attention though.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear: `decimal.Parse` is not able to convert whatever value you have in `e.Row.Cells[4]`. What's the value there?

Try doing like this:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    string recNUnits = e.Row.Cells[4].Text;

    recomN.Text = recNUnits;

    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[4].Text))
    {
        recommend = decimal.Parse(e.Row.Cells[4].Text);
    }

    calcNtoApply();
 }
```